# In SQLite, is there a limit for values in IN () statement

Tags: sqlite

I am updating a number of rows in an SQLite database, currently one-by-one. With the (unique) values indexed, this is acceptably fast.

Currently the number of rows are up to 10.000 approx, but could be more.

Out of curiousity, I wondered if it would be more efficient to use an IN () statement, so the update would be something like

```
   update logfile set exported=1 where uniqValue IN (
      'abc123',
      'def987'
    .....
   )
```

and in that relation, **is there a limit to the number of values in that list ?**
Similar to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228695/is-there-any-limit-for-in-results-in-sql-server) for MSSQL

Comment: Just like in the linked question, the answer is "don't do it". Load values into a temporary table instead.

Comment: @mustaccio, so something like `update x set y=1 where uniq IN (select * from other_table)` ?  (after inserting values into other_table of course)